# Multinomial distribution question

Tags: probability, statistics, multinomial-distribution

Let there be 12 different events with different probabilities of happening, each of which is known to us. How do we then find the probability that all the events happen at least once for a given number of trials

Comment: Use the converse probability: 1-probability that at most 11 events happen once.

Comment: This is the Coupon Collector's Problem with unequal probabilities.

Comment: @callculus42, I'm sorry I don't follow, could you please help me out a little more?

Comment: @totlay You calcuate the prob. no event occurs and the prob. that exacty one event occurs each (12 cases).  The you subtract the sum of the two probs. from $1$